# php mysql - how to get the id and the date from the link in the 1st page?

Tags: php, mysql, date, get

I have this link code from **clientsLoanview.php**

```
   $query = "SELECT MID,mem_name,loan_amount,advanced_interrest,pay_months,type,rel_date,due_date,collateral,rel_by,
                        (loan_amount * ((advanced_interrest/100) * pay_months)) as current,
                        ((loan_amount * ((advanced_interrest/100) * pay_months))+loan_amount) as payable
                     FROM loan_transaction order by rel_date ";
            $retrieve = mysql_query($query)or die("Query Failed:".mysql_error());


            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retrieve)){

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td id='row'>".$row['MID']."</td>";
                echo '<td id="row">'.$row["mem_name"].'</td>';
                echo '<td id="row">'.$row["loan_amount"].'</td>';
                echo '<td id="row">'.$row["advanced_interrest"].'</td>';
                echo '<td id="row">'.$row["current"].'</td>';
                echo '<td id="row">'.$row["payable"].'</td>';
                echo '<td id="row">'.$row["pay_months"].'</td>';
                echo '<td id="row">'.$row["type"].'</td>';
                echo '<td id="row">'.$row["rel_date"].'</td>';
                echo '<td id="row">'.$row["due_date"].'</td>';
                echo "<td id='row'> <a name='view' href='viewAllPersonalLoan.php?id=".$row['MID']."'> View </a> </td>";                 
                echo "<td id='row'> <a name='view' href='viewPersonalLoan.php?id=".$row['MID'].",date=".$row['rel_date']."'> View </a> </td>";
            }
        ?>
```

I wanted to get the id and the date of that specific line having the specified id provided in the while loop (i.e id=1 and date =2015-2-26). This code won't work.

```
    echo "<td id='row'> <a name='view' href='viewPersonalLoan.php?id=".$row['MID'].",date=".$row['rel_date']."'> View </a> </td>";
```

Please help me to get the right syntax so that i may use this or any other that may apply for the next page.

**viewPersonalLoan.php**

```
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $date=$_GET['date'];
```

Thank you for your answer. Please help me with this. ;*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass more than one parameter, you will need to concatenate them using `&`, not `,`:

```
echo "<td id='row'> <a name='view' href='viewPersonalLoan.php?id=".$row['MID']."&amp;date=".$row['rel_date']."'> View </a> </td>";
```

Make sure to escape the `&` to `&amp;`.

Comment: "Make sure to escape the & to &amp;" um NO

Comment: Not? Am I not up-to-date on this anymore? How would you prevent it from starting an HTML entity?

Comment: if its not for display, never use HTML entity, if it is then you should really be using utf8 anyway - of course i have be known to be wrong

Comment: i'm so sorry for that. thank you for the link. i'm just a newbie here. thanks again for reminding.

Comment: i'm currently reading the link of how to accept answers. i though for accepting answers is just to accept the code. i was wrong though. well, thanks again.

Comment: @sw8mom You're welcome and thank you. Plus, you get extra rep when you do ;-)

Comment: yup! i do. Thanks. so, can i ask it again pls? can someone pls help me with this too? [how to sum up the total amount of the selected date and id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749742/php-mysql-how-to-update-the-remaining-payable-after-every-payment) thank you